# which key is used for meta in Emacs on modern keyboards

Tags: keyboard, emacs

I get that some people use their <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key but I have a hard time imagining that people use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key left to the <kbd>Space</kbd> bar as meta key since it is inconvenient to type in combination with other keys.

So what key do people use for their meta key in Emacs?

Comment: I either preface the command with `ESC`, or hold down the `ALT` key as I type the command. What's a "modern keyboard"?

Comment: any standard fairly new keyboard without a dedicated meta key but with arrow keys ; ) But isnt having to press the alt key left tothe space bar a drag? I would rather like to press the Alt Gr key to the right of the keyboard but I cant manage to permanently map this key to alt 's functionality

Comment: @CarstenD What keyboard layout are you using, in hardware and software?

Comment: freaking german one. I bound ctrl to caps lock for easier reach but am wondering what people usually use as meta key since I think alt, left to space, is difficult to reach, especially in combination with other keys